# This row was already applied and cannot be modified

Tags: apache-kudu

When i run my code in the test environment to test my new code about kudu insert,it reports to me:

> This row was already applied and cannot be modified.

I have already tried to debug my code and to see what is the problem in my code , but it is useless

```
if((map.get(list.get(i))) instanceof Double){
    row.addDouble(list.get(i), (Double) map.get(list.get(i)));
    //System.out.println("Double type insert succeed ： " + list.get(i) + "  :  " + map.get(list.get(i)));
    continue;
}
```

I want to know what's wrong in my code because in my previous code i can run correct but know it cannot

Answer (score 0):

In the source code ,The class was that PartialRow has a private propertiy:frozen, It's default value was false,but in my code,when i debug in it,i found that value was true,I think this is the reason that cause the program reports to my : This row was alredy applied and cannot be modified ！ asking for help .please

Answer (score 0):

Without full stacktrace and the rest of code I can only guess why this is happening.

My guess is because the `Insert` object on which this `row` object is created has already inserted to Kudu (using `KuduSession.apply`) and then you tried to update it using `row.addDouble`.

If you are unsure about why please see this [example of how to insert into Kudu.](https://github.com/apache/kudu/blob/master/examples/java/java-example/src/main/java/org/apache/kudu/examples/Example.java#L90)
`KuduSession.apply` method is invoked on `Insert` object on which `PartialRow` object is created, this will insert the data from all the `PartialRow` objects created from the `Insert` object. This can be done only once on one `Insert` object. After that you create a new `Insert` object using `KuduTable.newInsert()`

In your case you should probably create new object of `Insert` using `KuduTable.newInsert()` and create a row object on this.